# htaccesc rewrite rule does not work

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
<Files ~ (\.php)>
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch 
</Files>
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?lang=$1&menu=$2&submenu=$3 [L]
```

origin url: example.com/index.php?lang=de&menu=1&submenu=0
new url: example.com/de/1/0

new url load main page, but need another page

Comment: What is the question exactly and what is the problem you are facing? At this moment we can't answer anything based on the current information.

Comment: question: Why url "example.com/de/1/0" does not working like url "example.com/index.php?lang=de&menu=1&submenu=0"

Comment: on this page "example.com/index.php?lang=de&menu=1&submenu=0" I have "About company", but this url "example.com/de/1/0" load "Home page". In rewrite url I also need "About company"

Answer (score 0):

```
<Files ~ (\.php)>
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch 
</Files>
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?lang=$1&menu=$2&submenu=$3 [L]
```

If you follow this, you told Apache to take everything that is not a file or a directory in the file system and rewrite it to index.php.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

So that's what it is doing.

To make this do what you want, you have to make it like this:

```
<Files ~ (\.php)>
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch 
</Files>
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
# if file/director does not exist, and if it matches the pattern
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?lang=$1&menu=$2&submenu=$3 [QSA,L]
# then if it did not match the pattern, send it to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Note that you did not provide enough information to understand what you are actually trying to achieve. But my guess is it's something like this. I'm also assuming that you want to append the values to the query string of index.php (QSA), which is usually what you want.

But it's not really possible to guess further until you specify what all the urls are supposed to do.

Note that by matching anything not file/directory, and rewriting it without further argument as the last command to index.php (L), that ends the request processing, it will never hit the second case.